# How do I install Composer PHP packages without Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to install the Coinbase PHP API but it requires Composer:

https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php

I'm looking for a universal PHP solution (perhaps a function) to let me install composer packages directly onto my server, without having to use Composer.

Comment: All packages using composer are still mere directories full of PHP files. You can install them exactly the same way you did before composer existed: copy them somewhere and `include` the files.

Comment: Composer-based installation implies running a single command, which is almost always shown in the package home page. I understand there're use cases for manual installation but it's never going to be the easier method.

Comment: @dallin Despite the title, that article is mostly a rant about modern over-engineered frameworks and tool-chains (a problem of its own). If you want to install a library that happens to have 30 dependencies, dumping Composer in favour of 30 manual installs can make you feel more manly or whatever, but I wouldn't call it easier, much less for beginner developers.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález To be honest, I haven't had to install a library with 30 dependencies (sounds poorly designed tbh). I'm sure it would be a nightmare without a package manager. My experiences though are similar to that article. I usually try to install something with one or two dependencies and end up having to spend my time troubleshooting the issues with the package manager before I even start coding. Error messages are way too frequent and incredibly vague and esoteric. This might illustrate my feelings better: https://imgur.com/r/webdev/bO7oTf6. My experiences with PM's have been similar.

Comment: Composer is **just a php script**. So using Composer is **literally**  "a universal PHP solution"

Comment: 1-Install a local server like Wamp. 2-Install composer in local. 3-Install your package with Composer to create the "vendor/" directory of the library. 4-Use it in a server without composer :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The [`composer.json` file](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-php/blob/master/composer.json) lists the dependencies. In your example:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.0",
    "psr/http-message": "^1.0",
    "psr/log": "^1.0"
},
```

You must then find the corresponding packages in the [packagist](https://packagist.org/) site. Repeat the same process for each dependency: find additional dependencies in their corresponding `composer.json` files and search again.

When you finally have a complete list of the required packages, you only need to install them all one by one. For the most part, it's just a matter of dropping the files somewhere in your project directory. But you must also ensure that PHP can find the needed classes. Since you aren't using Composer's auto-loader, you need to add them to your own custom autoloader. You can figure out the information from the respective `composer.json` files, e.g.:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Coinbase\\Wallet\\": "src/" }
},
```

If you don't use a class auto-loader you'll need to figure out the individual `require_once` statements. You'll probably need a lot of trial and error because most library authors won't care documenting that.

Also, and just in case there's confusion about this:

- Composer has an official GUI installer for Windows and a *copy and paste* command-line installation procedure for all platforms.
- Composer can be run locally and its output just uploaded elsewhere. You don't need SSH in your shared hosting.
- The command needed to install a library can be copied and pasted from the package web site—even if the package maintainer didn't care to document it, packagist.org generates it by default.

Composer is not perfect and it doesn't suit all use cases but, when it comes to installing a library that relies on it, it's undoubtedly the best alternative and it's a fairly decent one.

---

I've checked other answers that came after mine. They mostly fall in two categories:

1. Install a library and write a custom download script with it
2. Use an online web based interface for Composer

Unless I'm missing something, none of them address the complaints expressed by the OP:

- Learning curve
- Use of third-party software
- Possibility to develop right on the server (using SSH, I presume)
- Potentially deep dependency tree

Comment: If this doesn't convince everyone to just use composer, nothing will…

Comment: First of all the current version of composer needs proc_open() which is not available everywhere. And there are other problems as well. While I agree that composer has its merits I have always known I would run into a problem one day and this day was it. I have yet to figure out how to install a shared library for 50+ client applications (using Composer).

Comment: I wish library devs would stop using composer. Its a no-go in any serious production environment. People who hide behind 'just use composer' have no idea what they are doing in the first place.

Comment: **laughs in JS**

Comment: I presume that what @ObedMarquezParlapiano is trying to say is that package management is just a tool to address project dependencies, and complaints about the former are often caused by the latter because at least the PHP de-facto standard tool is reasonably reliable, as anyone who's struggled with Node.js's NPM can assert. Of course, I may be wrong.

Comment: That's the best explanation of a sarcastic comment I've ever seen in my entire life. And you're correct, which makes it even better.

Comment: That sucks so much to do and write... kudos to all people who do this

Comment: "If this doesn't convince everyone to just use composer, nothing will…"

It didn't. It convinced me to "kill it with fire". "It" being League\CommonMark. Markdown boasts with being "a lightweight markup language". But wanting to parse it with PHP just seems to also require PSD Event Dispatcher and Symfony in addition to the 14491 LOC in CommonMark! Fourteenthousand! Lines! Of! Code!

Comment: @Alien426 Now, imagine having to figure out by yourself that you need to install PSD Event Dispatcher and Symfony.

Comment: You mean without composer.json? A thinking developer would just disclose that information front and center (or not have dependencies). So, yes, with software quality being the way it is for a reason, it would be hard to figure that out. The recent tendency to fragment the code into many small files (League\CommonMark: 272 files, 70 directories) does not help either. (Where does that come from? University? Git?) I will not use Composer. I will not use League\CommonMark. There's a Python module that you can just unzip (18 files, 2 dirs), throw into Python's directory and it works.

Comment: @Alien426 Hi, author of league/commonmark here. I'm sorry you feel that way. Version 1.6 has no external dependencies so you're welcome to use that, just know that it's no longer supported.

Comment: Well I dont want to use Packagist...

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz You can clone the repository and feed Composer with that. Please check the [VCS repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs) feature.

Answer (score 25):

I'm using shared hosting for a website and can't execute commands there. Aside from running composer via php script request that I request via browser, I usually use this workflow:

- Make sure you have php installed locally.
- Make directory on desktop.
- download composer.phar from https://getcomposer.org/download/ (under header ***Manual Download**) and place it in the directory.
- make a file *composer.json* paste in it the following contents

  ```
   {
       "require": {
           "coinbase/coinbase": "~2.0"
       }
   }
  ```
- Browse to the directory with the shell of your choice(bash, git-bash, cmd, windows bash)
- type `php composer.phar update` [image: screenshot of bash output]
- Upload the vendor directory to your webserver via ftp or whatever mechanic you use.
- include in your php project where you load your libraries(modify path to where you uploaded the vendor dir so it will include that autoload file)

  ```
  require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
  ```

This way you get the benefit of dependency management and you don't have to include manually all the gazillion of files and download all the dependencies manually, and updating them is just as easy as typing `php composer.phar update` and then replacing the vendor dir on your server with the new one.

Answer (score 9):

An alternative solution that worked for me (since php-download was down) can be done by making your own little local composer downloader.

1. Download and install XAMPP locally: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html
2. Download and install composer locally: https://getcomposer.org/download/
3. Open commandprompt, navigate to say `c:\temp` and and simply type the composer dependancy, for example: `composer require league/oauth2-client`
4. Copy the files from your `c:\temp` folder to your web host using an FTP program
5. Add this to the top of your php: `require("vendor/autoload.php");`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks for this :)

Answer (score 5):

This is not the ultimate solution but for me it was a big help for most of the cases:
https://github.com/Wilkins/composer-file-loader

> Allow you to load composer.json file just as composer would do it.
>   This allow you to load composer.json file without composer (so
>   theorically PHP 5.2 is enough)

I know the question is old but I hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do this for an FTP server I didn't have SSH access to.  The site listed in here worked, then I realized you can just do a composer install on your own server (using your target's PHP version), then copy all the files over.

Comment: @IchHabsDrauf Basically he ment to use composer (at this part, its not really the anwser) and than copy over files to production enviroment. My comment to that would be that maybe there are people without composer on dev enviroment too, thus this is not really an anwser.

Answer (score 3):

## Analizing the problem

The problem in installing the dependencies **without Composer** is the autoloading system.

Composer use a homemade autoloader based on an array map, this is a *de-facto standard*.
But this autoloading system, "fortunally" in this case, is not PSR-4 compliant.

PSR-4 is the *de-iure standard* for autoload a class in PHP, so you can't escape from autoloading. You must use one of them.

## Solution Proposal

In this case, [this brilliant PSR-4 autoloader](https://github.com/MarcoConsiglio-Wichee/PSR-4-Autoloading) is capable to be manually configured to autoload a `VendorClass` in a `VendorNamespace` anywhere in your code, as long as you require the custom `autoload.php` file early in your source code.

## Real life example

Let's look at this example:
I have a legacy project who can't and won't use Composer never and never even if God allow this with a miracle. This project can be speed up in development with this fantastic [package for command line scripts](https://github.com/nategood/commando).
This is my project directory structure:

```
 - src
 - tests
 - vendor (not the Composer's one)
```

This package has this directory structure:

```
 - examples
 - src
   - Commando
 - tests
```

The only thing I need is the `src` folder. Placing this folder in my vendor folder would be fine. So my custom autoloader would be like this:

```php
// Constants
$base_path = "path\to\my\project";
$autoloader_class = '\vendor\MarcoConsiglio-Wichee\PSR-4-Autoloading\Psr4AutoloaderClass.php';
define("BASE_PATH", str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $base_path));

// Autoloader
require_once BASE_PATH.'\vendor\MarcoConsiglio-Wichee\PSR-4-Autoloading\Psr4AutoloaderClass.php';

// Init the autoloader.
$package = [
    "nategood\commando" => [
        "namespace" => "Commando",
        "path" => str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '\vendor\nategood\commando\src\Commando')
    ],
    "kevinlebrun\colors.php" => [
        "namespace" => "Colors",
        "path" => str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '\vendor\kevinlebrun\colors.php\src\Colors')
    ]
];

// Register namespaces.
$loader = new \PSR4\Psr4AutoloaderClass;
$loader->register();
                      // Namespace                                      // Path to source
$loader->addNamespace($package["nategood\commando"]["namespace"],       BASE_PATH.$package["nategood\commando"]["path"]);
$loader->addNamespace($package["nategood\commando"]["namespace"],       BASE_PATH.$package["nategood\commando"]["path"]."\Util");
$loader->addNamespace($package["kevinlebrun\colors.php"]["namespace"],  BASE_PATH.$package["kevinlebrun\colors.php"]["path"]);
```

Now I can use the command package anywhere in my project!

## Pros & Cons

This solution allow you to:

- Easely and manually build your own custom autoloader (you only need to specify the `VendorNamespace` and the folder(s) where search for `VendorClass`es in the `VendorNamespace`.
- Freely organize your composer dependency anywhere in your project folder (and why not, outside it)
- Import a composer package as is in your project (either downloading locally with Composer or cloning the package repository) or a relevant part of it (i.e removing composer.json file or files that require the composer autoloader).

Cons:

- Manually build your custom autoloader means to work on **every** required dependency of your project (i hope not a lot).
- Mistakes in package source paths can be tedious and frustrating.
- Works only with PSR-4 compliant file names (i.e. can't use a `A.class.php` file name)

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a python script that generates the `autoload.php`.

1. In `composer.json`, find the `autoload.psr-4` and copy the library path (in my case `src/Pecee`):

```json
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Pecee\\": "src/Pecee"
    }
}
```

2. Copy and paste this python script and replace the path with yours.

```py
import os

# adjust the path (in my case the script was already in `src` directory)
path = "."

with open("autoload.php", "w") as file:
    file.write("<?php\n")

    for item in os.walk(path):
        dirname = item[0]
        for filename in item[2]:
            file.write("require_once \"" + dirname + "/" + filename + "\";\n")
```

This script generates an `autoload.php` file that can be imported into a php file. Example:

```php
<?php
require_once "./Pecee/Exceptions/InvalidArgumentException.php";
require_once "./Pecee/SimpleRouter/SimpleRouter.php";
require_once "./Pecee/SimpleRouter/IRouterBootManager.php";
require_once "./Pecee/SimpleRouter/Router.php";
...
```

#### You will need to change the order of `require_once` based on the error messages that will popup.

Enable error messages and import `autoload.php`:

```php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once "./autoload.php";
```