# Installing doctrine without composer

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I've downloaded doctrine 2.5.9 and I'm following the doc but in doc the installation uses composer and it loads doctrine with the autoload.php file, what file I have to include to use doctrine if I dont't have an autoload.php file  because I'm not using composer?

Comment: is there any reason why you're not using composer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install Composer PHP packages without Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545795/how-do-i-install-composer-php-packages-without-composer)

Comment: Limited acces to server, it's not on me

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545795/how-do-i-install-composer-php-packages-without-composer

Comment: Why don't you install doctrine on your localhost, and then upload it to the server. If it is due to limited server access.

Comment: Limited access to local computer too,I'd use composer If I could

Comment: Then just download it from github and upload it.

Comment: upload it  its not the problem ,the problem its what file do I have to include in my code to use Doctrine

Comment: Use composer to install on your local development machine then upload to your limited access server.  Be sure to upload the vendor directory.  That will give you the autoload stuff.