# TYPO3 8.7 Install an extension without composer

Tags: composer-php, typo3

I have a T3 8 project that was installed WITHOUT composer.
For the project I need the Ext t3api, which can only be installed (???) WITH composer.
Is it possible to install it somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Composer PHP packages without Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545795/how-do-i-install-composer-php-packages-without-composer)

Answer (score 1):

EXT:t3api is available via TER (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/t3api). So it's installable via extensionmanager.

Another way would be uploading the extension's folder to `typo3conf/ext/` (foldername = extensionkey - in this case "t3api"). Then the extensionmanager will find it and allow you to active/install it.

**Update:**

Dependencies to PHP packages (like some symfony/* packages) cannot be handled directly by TYPO3 (`ext_emconf.php`). Therefore, you have to build your own extension with the code of these packages and configure the appropriate autoloading.

There's already a good thread "[How do I install Composer PHP packages without Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40545795/6783328)"

Comment: The extension is shipped without dependencies. It's not possible to use it.
Is it possible to install dependencies manually?

Comment: Uff... There are dependencies to PHP packages like some symfony/* packages in the composer.json. IMO, TYPO3 can not handle this directly via `ext_emconf.php`, but only dependencies to other TYPO3 extensions.
Maybe, it's possible to build an extension that has the needed packages in `Resources/Private/PHP/`). But I'm not sure how to address/include/autoload/... these classes than...

Comment: "How do I install Composer PHP packages without Composer?" https://stackoverflow.com/q/40545795/6783328