# How to use a PHP package via Github manually instead of composer

Tags: php, github, smtp, composer-php

I have a very quick and simple question, I want to use this PHP package: https://github.com/zytzagoo/smtp-validate-email to validate if an email exist, but in the documentation of installation it only show how to install via composer and I want to install it manually (downloading the package and add it to my project).

In the example with composer it's like this:

```
composer require zytzagoo/smtp-validate-email --update-no-dev
```

And to use it is like this

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use SMTPValidateEmail\Validator as SMTP_Validate_Email;
```

I just want to know what should I do for a manually installation instead of the composer

Comment: Include/require any file from the `src` folder

Comment: You already answered your question yourself: "downloading the package and add it to my project" ... So what is your _real_ question?

Comment: @arkascha what should I put instead of: require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use SMTPValidateEmail\Validator as SMTP_Validate_Email;

Comment: Depends on _where_ you install that package in your project. `require` simply includes a file it finds under a given relative path. So use the relative path to the class of that package you want to require and that's it. Invest a bit of trial and error if you are unsure. I am sure you will master this.

Comment: anything you write in symphony /laravel / wordpress and other "solution" is a very lagy bad experience for the user and cut O2 you should breathe cause the sever when several requests are made and this software is abusing the hardware(cpu,memory,..)

Comment: the server to avoid heat is starting the cooler(s) .. this in countries where energy isn't produce from 100% clean sources!  so tomorrow dioxide carbon cut more O2 , Ozone shield and your bad move and others comes back as bad very bad feedback ! the solution ? activate mysqli extension(even sqlite3 in some cases) and write first a library (one include file with several functions = reusable code) ,then when you learn more write your fist micro framework , then a framework and whatever you do of these learn to use apache tools bencmark , microsoft's task manager in Windows 10 ,11 with cpu uses

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Composer PHP packages without Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40545795/how-do-i-install-composer-php-packages-without-composer)